# Custom AOV output based on diffuse BSDF or principled BSDF appears black in Eevee

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, output

Lighting information from diffuse or Principled BSDF, through shader to RGB appears black in renders when used in AOV output.
Is there a different way to achieve the same result that worked in 2.93?

[image: black in 3.3.1]

[image: worked in 2.93]

Comment: Same for me https://imgur.com/2ghMaJ2 ... try to check bug tracker is posted (if not go to Blender menu > Help > Bug Report)

Comment: Thanks, It was the 1st time I reported a bug, so I entered it directly on the site yesterday:
[https://developer.blender.org/T102434](https://developer.blender.org/T102434)

Comment: Thank you and congratulation :)